# Inserir linha a partir de um critério

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

É possivel criar uma macro que ao usuário clicar em um botão, crie automaticamente uma linha acima de um determinado critério?

Como na imagem a seguir demonstra, isso é um cronograma de férias, e nessa mesma planilha tenho 3 botões que deveriam adicionar uma linha dentro desses três campos GERENTES, GEPEJ, GEPEF e para isso pensei em ao usuário clicar neste botão, a macro encontra por exemplo "GEPEJ" e adiciona uma linha acima dela, para usuario preencher, e por ai vai... O mesmo para as outras

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Macro que fiz até o momento é essa:

Porém ela está encontrando a partir de uma linha especifica como "A15" então desse modo ele sempre vai criar linhas a partir dessa célula, o que não é legal para esse caso pois ele deve inserir sempre na ultima linha do campo "GERENTES" e para isso teria que ser como criterio a palavra GEPEJ, que adiciona 1 linha acima dele, ficando no campo desejado.

```html
 Range("A15").Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Insert
  Rows("14:14").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rows("14:15"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Rows("14:15").Select
    Range("E15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("B15").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você está buscando depende de uma referência relativa e o seu código (tentativa) é absoluto ao número da linha, ou seja, sempre executa naquele lugar (linha).

```
Sub inserirLinha()

Dim textoPesquisa As String
Dim pesquisaLinha As Integer

textoPesquisa = "GEPEJ"

pesquisaLinha = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(textoPesquisa, Columns("B:B"), 0)

Rows(pesquisaLinha - 1).Insert

End Sub
```

Fiz um exemplo usando variáveis (anote para estudo), onde a `pesquisaLinha` identifica qual o número da linha que possui o `textoPesquisa`.
Após, insere uma nova linha, considerando que é o número retornado na busca menos 1, ou seja, na linha acima.

Deixei aberto para ficar mais explicativo, pois poderia ser ainda reduzido para:

```
Sub inserirLinha2()

Rows(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("GEPEJ", Columns("B:B"), 0) - 1).Insert

End Sub
```

Com esse conhecimento você pode adaptar de acordo com as suas necessidades.

Além disso, outras melhorias podem/devem ser feitas, como tratamento de erros (caso não ache o textoPesquisa, por exemplo), ou deixar a declaração de referência de forma completa (nome do arquivo e sheet), evitando eventuais erros com muitas macros/arquivos em paralelo.

Comment: É possivel fazer uma macro também que encontra a palavra que eu quero, como GEPEJ, e a partir dela ele arrasta a alça de preenchimento até encontrar um valor que eu determine? por exemplo: 1, a macro vai encontrar a palavra GEPEJ, vai arrastar a alça de preenchimento e quando encontrar o número 1 da coluna B ele para

Comment: Jean, muito obrigado, isso ajudou demais! Mas queria saber como posso inserir um valor a cada uma dessas linhas criadas? por exemplo, ao criar a linha com essa macro, gostaria de inserir o valor 0 na coluna E, a cada linha que for gerado, na coluna dessa linha insere o valor = 0